# How to create and close a Database connection dynamically with Request Scope Providers in Nestjs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I am Working on a project with Nestjs 7.x, Mongoose, Mongo, etc., Regarding to the Back End, in my use case, I must change the connection of one of my databases depending on some conditions/parameters coming from some requests. I am able to change the connections but **I want to close the mongoose connection after each request succeeded**.

hers is my code

```
"@nestjs/mongoose": "7.0.0",
"mongoose": "5.10.1"
```

```js
/*************************
* mognoose.service.ts
*************************/
import { Inject, Injectable, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseOptionsFactory, MongooseModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class MongooseConfigService implements MongooseOptionsFactory {
    constructor(
        @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request,) {
    }

    createMongooseOptions(): MongooseModuleOptions {
        return {
            uri: request.params.uri, // Change this to whatever you want; you have full access to the request object.
        };
    }
}

/*************************
* mongoose.module.ts
*************************/
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { MongooseConfigService } from 'mognoose.service';

@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
            useClass: MongooseConfigService,
        }),
    ]
})
export class DbModule {}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: @ParthDhankecha Not yet :(